# ".exe\",0" Was unexpected at this time." Error when using parentheses in file name

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to register my application in the windows registry but there it seems that there is something wrong in my code:

```
@echo off

set "APP=MyApp"
set "APP_NAME=App"
set "APP_PATH=D:\proj 100\1\test 1(64-bit).exe"
set "APP_ICON=\"%APP_PATH%\",0"
set "APP_ARGS=\"%APP_PATH%\" \"%%1\""

if not exist "%APP_PATH%" (

echo ERROR: "%APP_PATH%" not found.

) else (


reg add "HKLM\Software\Classes\%APP%HTML" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "%APP_NAME% Document" /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Classes\%APP%HTML\DefaultIcon" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "%APP_ICON%" /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Classes\%APP%HTML\shell\open\command" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "%APP_ARGS%" /f

)

pause
```

I keep getting this error

```
.exe\",0" was unexpected at this time.
```

**Edit:**
I had changed the file name output after testing the code, the original name was `test 1(64-bit).exe`, so apparently it only happens when the file name/path has parentheses. I tried to escape the characters but it did not work.

Comment: I'd suggest that the `\"` sequence should be removed from each of the variables in which it is used, and that `%%1` should then be `"%%1"`, but I've not tried it - I don't play games with the registry.

Comment: Put `set APP_` after the variable assignments and post the output ([edit] the question for that)…

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you it seems that it only happens when i use parenthesis in the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted batch code does not work because of `)` in the file name in the command line with all environment variable references already expanded

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Classes\MyAppHTML\DefaultIcon" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "\"D:\proj 100\1\test 1(64-bit).exe\",0" /f
```

is interpreted as end of the `else` command block because of being outside a double quoted argument string. For the Windows command processor the first argument string after **REG** option `/d` is `"\"` and so `D:\proj 100\1\test 1(64-bit)` is outside of a double quoted argument string.
See also: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

The following batch code avoiding command blocks would be better:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "APP_FILE=D:\proj 100\1\test 1(64-bit).exe"
if not exist "%APP_FILE%" echo ERROR: "%APP_FILE%" not found.& exit /B 1

set "RegExe=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"
if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe set "RegExe=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe"

set "APP=MyApp"
set "APP_NAME=App"
set "APP_ICON=\"%APP_FILE%\",0"
set "APP_ARGS=\"%APP_FILE%\" %%1"

%RegExe% ADD "HKLM\Software\Classes\%APP%HTML" /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%APP_NAME% Document" >nul
if errorlevel 1 echo ERROR: %~nx0 must be run as administrator.& exit /B
%RegExe% ADD "HKLM\Software\Classes\%APP%HTML\DefaultIcon" /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%APP_ICON%" >nul
%RegExe% ADD "HKLM\Software\Classes\%APP%HTML\shell\open\command" /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%APP_ARGS%" >nul

endlocal
```

There is first defined the environment variable `APP_FILE` and then checked the existence of this file with printing an error message to standard output handle and exiting the processing of the batch file with error exit code 1 on application executable not existing.

The batch file is designed to work on 32-bit and 64-bit Windows and runs on 64-bit Windows always 64-bit `reg.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` even on batch file being processed by 32-bit `cmd.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`. See the Microsoft documentation pages:

1. [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)
2. [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
3. [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys)

There is used the option `/ve` instead of `/v ""` as explained by the usage help output on running `reg add /?` in a command prompt window.

The double quotes around `%1` are removed because of Windows File Explorer adds itself double quotes to the argument string passed to the executable if that is necessary like on argument string containing a space character. However, it would be also possible to use:

```
set "APP_ARGS=\"%APP_FILE%\" \"%%1\""
```

The batch file adds on success to the Windows registry:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppHTML]
@="App Document"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppHTML\DefaultIcon]
@="\"D:\\proj 100\\1\\test 1(64-bit).exe\",0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppHTML\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppHTML\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyAppHTML\shell\open\command]
@="\"D:\\proj 100\\1\\test 1(64-bit).exe\" %1"
```

The batch file above does not work correct on fully qualified file name assigned to the environment variable `APP_FILE` contains an ampersand `&` like with a path `C:\Temp\Development & Test!` as used in the batch file below using delayed variable expansion for handling such an unusual path, too.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "APP_FILE=C:\Temp\Development & Test!\test 1(64-bit).exe"
if not exist "%APP_FILE%" echo ERROR: "%APP_FILE%" not found.& exit /B 1

set "RegExe=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"
if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe set "RegExe=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "APP=MyApp"
set "APP_NAME=App"
set "APP_ICON=\"!APP_FILE!\",0"
set "APP_ARGS=\"!APP_FILE!\" %%1"
rem set "APP_ARGS=\"!APP_FILE!\" \"%%1\""

%RegExe% ADD "HKLM\Software\Classes\%APP%HTML" /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%APP_NAME% Document" >nul
if errorlevel 1 echo ERROR: %~nx0 must be run as administrator.& exit /B
%RegExe% ADD "HKLM\Software\Classes\%APP%HTML\DefaultIcon" /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d "!APP_ICON!" >nul
%RegExe% ADD "HKLM\Software\Classes\%APP%HTML\shell\open\command" /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d "!APP_ARGS!" >nul

endlocal
endlocal
```

Please note that neither `if` nor `echo` nor `exit` modify the value of dynamic variable `ERRORLEVEL` and for that reason the second `exit /B` results also in an exit of batch file processing with error exit code `1` as set by `reg.exe`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `if /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg add /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&`.